# Select2 callback or event after the menu has been built

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

For this I am dynamically recoloring each option in the select.  I have tried both open and opening and when they are called the menu that is being created yet exists.

```
$(document).on("select2:opening", function () {
    console.log('Here', $('#select2-SELECTNAME-results li').length);
    $('#select2-SELECTNAME-results li').each(function(k,ele){
        console.log(k, $(ele).text());
        $(ele).css('background-color', COLOROBJECT[k]).addClass('text-shadow');
    });
});
```

If I run the code after it has created the menu, it works great.  I need a callback that would tell me when the menu has been created.  Does this exist and I am missing it, or is this a feature that is missing from, or outside the scope of, select2?

Answer (score 0):

Select2 has the `templateResult` configuration that allows you to change the appearance of the dropdown. See here: https://select2.org/dropdown

An example:

```
$("#select2-SELECTNAME-results").select2({
     ...
     templateResult: function(data) {
          return '<li class="text-shadow" style="background-color:' + COLOROBJECT[k] + '" >' + data.text + '</li>';
     }
     ...
})
```

Comment: I have tried that, but you are unable to alter the actually li, so it just has horrible padding/margining.